# Eager Loading Children for a LINQ stored procedure call

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, asp.net-3.5

I have a special stored procedure that returns a List of Distributors from my database.  I then iterate through the loop of Distributors and output the results to a web page.  However, I need to load the State and the Country for each Distributor.  I would rather do this one time, before the loop so that the page is faster.  This is my code:

```
List<Distributor> distQuery =  connection.spDistFindLocal(Lat, Long).ToList<Distributor>();
```

I know I can do `distributor.State.Load();` on each element in my List but I think that is a poor choice.  What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a projection:

```
List<DistributorViewModel> distQuery =  
    (from d in connection.spDistFindLocal(Lat, Long)
     select new DistributorViewModel
     {
         Name = d.Name,
         State = d.State.Name,
         Country = d.Country.Name
     })ToList();
```

Not only does this load all of the data in one query, but it also omits loading the properties you don't care about for this view.

Comment: @Craig - Awesome I didn't even think about the problem in that way!  One question, I would need to declare what is in DistributorViewModel right?  If so where would I do that?  Is there an article somewhere that covers it?  This is new territory for me.  Thanks!

Comment: You can declare a new type anywhere in scope or you can use an anonymous type in some cases. [I wrote an article on this on my blog](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/)

Comment: @Craig - So it took me a while to get back to this but it totally works!  Love it thanks for the help. One thing on your blog post you have [Key, ScaffoldColumn(false)].  How/What is that used for? I created my presentation class inside of my page since I only used it one time.  When I tried to add that code VS2010 didn't recognize it at all.  I have upgraded to .Net 4 so not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: `ScaffoldColumn` (1) requires `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and (2) tellls MVC 2's templated views not to generate an editor for that property.

Comment: @Craig - Thanks!  I am not using MVC yet on my site so that isn't an issue.

Comment: It's also used by Dynamic Data. Not sure if anything else uses it.